# Number of $3$-Letter words from the alphabet {A, B, C} that have no $2$ "A's" directly one after the other

Tags: combinatorics

> What is the number of $3$-Letter words from the alphabet {A, B, C} that have no $2$ "A's" directly one after the other?

What am I doing wrong? I have the following calculation:

$(1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3) + (2 \cdot 1 \cdot 2) + (3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1) = 16$.

In each of the above parenthesis, $1$ stands for "A", and since no two "A's" are allowed one after the other, we multiply $1$ with the only $2$ options left (B and C). $3$ is a free slot in which we can use any letter from our alphabet.

This calculation is wrong, but I'm not sure why. My textbook gives $22$ as a solution. Where is my mistake?

Comment: You have $27=3^3$ words and AAA,AAB,AAC,BAA,CAA are forbidden.

Comment: If you're going to break your strings into cases, the cases need to account for every string exactly once. Your case 1 and case 3 both allow for some of the same strings that start with A (ABA, for example). None of your cases allow for strings that have no A's (BBB, for example).

Comment: I see my mistake now, thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Total number of allocations: $3 \times 3 \times 3 = 27$, because you have 3 slots and 3 letters/slot.

Allocations with 'banned' A: 2, $(AAx), (xAA)$. For each such allocation you have 3 choices $(A, B,C)$. Hence , $27- 2 \times 3 = 21$. Now, you have counted $AAA$ twice, add it from the solution: 
$$
27 - 2 \times 3 +1 = 22
$$

Answer (score 2):

Another way of solving this problem would be to look at the cases separately. We can at most have 2 "A's".

The possible number of cases with 0 "A's": 2 * 2 * 2 = 8 ( _ _ _ )

The possible number of cases with 1 "A's": 2 * 2 * 3 = 12 (A _ _, _ A _, _ _ A)

The possible number of cases with 2 "A's": 2 ( A _ A )

8 + 12 + 2 = 22

Comment: I like your answer. You could improve it even further by formatting your calculations using mathjax. See here for a quick introduction: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference. Note that users on this side might pay more attention to your posts if you format them properly.

Comment: @araomis I understand, thanks for letting me know that. I will check it out and try to write better answers!

Answer (score 1):

Reading the three products you have written, it seems to me that:

- your first case is when the first letter is $A$.
- your second case is when the first letter is not $A$ and the second is $A$.
- your third case is something I don't understand. I would assume that it should be the case where the first letter is not $A$ and the second isn't either, but your product $(3\cdot2\cdot 1)$ does not show any such thing.

Comment: For the third case, the first letter is A or B or C. The second letter is only B or C and the third letter is A.

Comment: @Karla You are counting some strings that start with A twice, and some others you are not counting at all.